# Gas company decided to shut off gas due to leak from backfeed

Tags: natural-gas

I decided to call Nicor Gas this morning, because I smelled some gas around the meters. They sent a technician out promptly, and found that there was a pipe pushing gas out the house from the same one feeding into the house. He wrote on the tag that gas had to be shut off due to safety relating to backfeed from fuel line that goes into the house. Sounds like contractors who did rehab tied two gas lines inside into one somewhere. The Nicor tech told me I have to hire a plumber to trace the pipe causing this. This house was converted from a 2 unit home to a single family. Is there anything i should be looking for before I call someone or just hire a plumber who specializes in gas plumbing?

Comment: I would contact a specialist gas plumber. Was there originally two gas meters and in conversion was one gas meter removed or disconnected?

Comment: I have found on ? Jobs that people that did not know what they were doing used electrical conduit couplers. Not pipe couplers. Conduit couplers are straight thread where black iron pipe couplers are tapered. Use a bubble solution on every coupling to detect leaks. I would suggest the type made for gas pipe it has a dye in it to make the bubbles more visible. A pressure test should also be done. With all the shutoff valves closed pressurize the system to 30-35 psi if there is any pressure drop in 60 minutes keep looking for the leaks. The gauge and bubble solution can be found at big box stores

Comment: @Octavio Nevarez follow Ed Beals' instructions he is correct about the pipe , it is easy to get some pipe mixed and the coupler's I guess too - they do this with water line versus conduit as well. Find the problem and have the correct components installed. You need to make sure this is done not just for the leak but also corrosion resistance.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. There was two meters at one point as this house was converted from a two unit to single family. One was removed. Gas company didn't properly cap or close off the pipe where they removed the meter as gas was still trying to go where that meter was.

Comment: @OctavioNevarez -- make that an answer and I'll give you an upvote

Comment: hmm, so you could have just left it off and enjoyed free gas from the other feed?

Answer (score 1):

If it was two homes there are probably two meters. If you see a second meter turn one off .If they are tied together anywhere the one working meter will feed everything.  If however they removed the meter and piped straight across where the meter used to be.... you have an un metered line feeding the house. That's the first thing to look for. The place where the second meter used to be. EITHER WAY HAVE A PROFESSIONAL HAVE A LOOK